# How to pass multiple arguments in a single Javascript method using thymeleaf onclick (th:onclick)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, thymeleaf, javascript-objects, spring-thymeleaf

I tried the following syntax but it didn't work for me. Please let me know the answer.

Javascript Code --->

```
function passValue(id, name){
        
        console.log(id)
        console.log(name)
    document.getElementById("updateId").value=id; 
        }
```

Thymeleaf code -->

```
<input type="button" th:onclick="passValue(\''+${data.id}+'\', \''+${data.newEntryName} +'\')" value="Update" />
```

It shows an error like:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected Token.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Did you check the resulting HTML in your browser? How does it look like? Is there any exception in the logs?

Comment: Thank you, Wim;
Yes, there it shows an error like; SyntaxError: Unexpected Token.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do JavaScript arguments like this (notice I'm using `onclick` and not `th:onclick`):

```
<input  type="button"
        th:data-id="${data.id}"
        th:data-name="${data.newEntryName}"
        onclick="passValue(this.getAttribute('data-id'), this.getAttribute('data-name'));"
        value="Update" />
```